# Laravel Class 'Iyzipay\Options' not found

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;


use Iyzipay\Options;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
  .
  .
  .

public function iyzico(Request $request){

    $name = $request->get('name');
    $card_no = $request->get('card_no');
    $expire_month = $request->get('expire_month');
    $expire_year = $request->get('expire_year');
    $cvc = $request->get('cvc');

    $user = Auth::user();


    //options
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setApiKey("***");
    $options->setSecretKey("***");
    $options->setBaseUrl("***");

}
.
.
.
}
```

I'm doing something like this on controller.But I get the error `Class 'Iyzipay\Options' not found`. I checked the file path and it is correct. No matter what I did I couldn't fix the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use iyzipay package, you should add to your composer:

```
composer require iyzico/iyzipay-php
```

**Edit For Manual Usage:**

If you want to use manual you can create Library folder under app directory. And paste iyzipay folder here.

Then create a file such as Iyzipay.php in Library folder.

```
app
-Library
--iyzipay-php
--Iyzipay.php
```

And Iyzipay.php (i recommend, don't use transaction process in your controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Library;

require_once dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/iyzipay-php/IyzipayBootstrap.php';

class Iyzipay
{

    public static function boot ()
    {
        \IyzipayBootstrap::init ();
    }

    public static function pay ( $apiInfo, $cartInfo, $price, $shippingTaxPrice = 0 )
    {
        ....
        ....

    }
}
```

and use in your controller like this:

```
<?php
...
...
use App\Library\Iyzipay;
...
...

Iyzipay::boot ();

$payment = Iyzipay::pay ( $apiResources, $cartInfo, $price) );
```

Comment: I encountered many errors when I did it this way. So I downloaded from Gtihub and copied the files.

Comment: But you don't include file. if you use manual, you should create Library folder in app folder and include iyzipay folder. I will update my answer

Comment: @furkanbozkurt kodu yazdim neredeyse onaylarsan sevinirim :)